# Pagination to viewing on one page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a module that displays registered and verified users for my CMS. The module is paginated displaying 10 on each page however I have a button that says "View All Members". What I'd like to know is how it would be possible for me the module to display ALL records on the page when the button is clicked and not sure how that would be possible. I am using PHP as well as jQuery.

Comment: what is the CMS? something homemade? open source? what module?

Comment: so is the problem trying to figure out how to write the query? or are you looking to have ajax load in all of the results to that same page?

Answer (score 0):

You're being pretty vague but how about making your button redirect to url like http://mycms.com/users/all where all is the same page as users without the pagination in place.